# "I'm curious as to how to…"

Tags: sentence, semantics, syntactic-analysis

Is that worded properly? I'm not sure if it's off. Thank you for any help you give.

Comment: It's not uncommon, but I prefer _I'm curious about how to_.

Comment: Please explain why you're confused about this. Consider the English Language Learners Stack Exchange might be more appropriate for this question.

Comment: @SrJoven This isn't a phrase I came across. I was about to use it, and I was unsure wether or not it was proper. I'm just not sure about things sometimes, so I ask.

Answer (score 4):

You can say that, however it sounds a bit more natural and casual to say:

"I'm curious about how to..."

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was just a bit unnatural sounding.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly an established phrasing.  Eg, "I'm curious as to how you intend to get the framix to interface with the wizgorf."  Maybe a little old-fashioned, but I (being an old<s>-fashioned</s> guy) would probably prefer it over "I'm curious about how ..."